# How to record all requests using VCR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rather big app, with remote requests in many places.

The only way I know how to add VCR is to add this type of block around every request test:

```
VCR.use_cassesse "whatever" do
  # request processing
end
```

But when you got 20 such requests - it may become too cluttered.

Is there a way to just edit VCR config file, so that it records all requests right away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test suite, you can insert/eject a cassette, this will record all the request within your test (*it* method call).

From my experience a cassette per *describe* is a good fit.

```
  before do
    VCR.insert_cassette 'whatever'
  end

  after do
    VCR.eject_cassette
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use VCR's request hooks to do this:

```
VCR.configure do |vcr|
  vcr.before_http_request do |request|
    cassette_name = cassette_name_for(request)
    VCR.insert_cassette(cassette_name) 
  end

  vcr.after_http_request do |request|
    VCR.eject_cassette
  end
end
```

This assumes you've written a `cassette_name_for` method that applies your cassette naming scheme based on the provided HTTP request.